# Unique URL for search optimization

Tags: url, seo, unique

Currently my website formats url this way:

http://www.filmitem.com/film/f152/

This page is already indexed by google and others.

I would like to make this url more friendly such as:

http://www.filmitem.com/film/f152/x-men-first-class

That means that the page will be accessible through:

http://www.filmitem.com/film/f152/ and
http://www.filmitem.com/film/f152/x-men-first-class

Will it affect indexing of my page in any way or is it better to have unique url for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a rel canonical link on the page to instruct Google et al. to use that form.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.filmitem.com/film/f152/x-men-first-class" />
```

Should be put in the `<head>` of your page.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow googlebots to crawl both pages then there shouldn't really be a problem with it being indexed. Just go onto google webmaster tools and get re indexed, its easy enough and making it more user friendly will problem get more hits.